# Angular library build error because of is not under 'rootDir'

Tags: angular6

I have created one angular project inside that I have created one library project. I have some common HTTP service placed inside the angular main project. I was trying to access the service file in the library project. when build the library, it showing the following error.

Any suggestion to share the common project service files to the library project. So that I can use the common service to any other library project.

> BUILD ERROR
>   error TS6059: File 'http.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'projects\device\src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Here is my source code.
[source code](https://github.com/smnss/test-library-project)

Comment: Did you get any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Did you get any solution for this ? I am facing the same issue.